# How to remap a option + i to give me ^, for then to press a vowel to use the accent in Karabiner

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

I recently changed the keyboard input to ABC - Extended because the normal one wouldn't let me type accents when the caps lock was on. Almost all of the are normal, but there are one there isn't. When I typed option + i, it gave me ^, and then I would press the vowel. But now it gives me '. Is there some way to do it in Karabiner? I tried playing with the config file but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

On ABC Extended, you press Option 6 for the ˆ accent deadkey before typing a vowel.

To see what all the keys do, you can use [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/13.0/mac/13.0).